# executeUpdate() in java takes long time to execute

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I am using a simple piece of code to update a single row in Oracle DB, the query updates just a single row but still the execution hangs on stmt.executeUpdate().

It does not throw any exception, but the control just hangs there.

I am lost here as the same piece of code worked fine earlier.

```
  try {
      DriverManager.registerDriver (new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,pwd);
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      String sql = "update report set status =" +"'"+NO+"'"+ " where name=" +"'"+ name+"'"+ " and user_id=" +"'"+sub+"'"; 
      System.out.println(sql);          
      stmt.executeUpdate(sql)
```

Comment: NEVER concatenate parameters into an SQL string like that.

Comment: use PreparedStatement and for this particular update put db indexies for 'name' nad 'user_id' columns

Comment: @NickJ but why? is that the cause ?

Comment: Do you have any other pending modification that is not yet committed? Maybe you have made modifications from sqlplus or Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: @RogerLindsjö i Checked that I have no pending modifications.

Comment: You may need an index- many records are in the report table, and what indexes do you have on that table?  (I also agree strongly with the PreparedStatement crowd, if only for the security reasons.)

Comment: Most likely your execution is very slow or blocked. Find your session in v$session view (sid, serial#). Then if on 11.2, look also these columns: EVENT, SEQ#, P1, P2,P3, STATE. If on version below 11.2, find corresponding line in v$session_wait. More info http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/dynviews_3016.htm#REFRN30223. Link for v$session wait on 10.2 http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2094.htm

Comment: NickJ: Never make a blanket "Never do this" statement without giving some sort of explanation. At least offer a different approach, if you're not going to explain why. A statement like yours simply provokes the question "why?".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should never create statements by concatenating variables like this. This leaves you open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Furthermore, each statement will be seen by Oracle as a new statement which will need a hard parse, which can lead to performance problems. Instead, use [preparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

However, I think that in your case it's not the cause of your problem. When a simple update hangs, it is almost always one of these reasons:

1. The row is locked by another transaction.
2. You are updating a key that is referenced by another table as an [unindexed foreign key](http://tkyte.blogspot.fr/2009/10/httpasktomoraclecomtkyteunindex.html).
3. The table has an ON UPDATE trigger that does lots of works.

I'm pretty sure that you're in the first case. Oracle prevents multiple users from updating the same row at the same time, for consistency reasons mostly. This means that a DML statement will wait upon another transaction if the modified row is locked. It will wait until the blocking transaction commits or rollbacks.

I advise you to always lock a row before trying to update it by doing a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE NOWAIT` before. This will fail if the row is already locked, and you can exit gracefully by telling the user that this row is currently being locked by another session.

You also have to make sure that no transaction ends in an uncommited state. All sessions should commit or rollback their changes before exiting (don't use autocommit though).

Answer (score 1):

Use JDBC PreparedStatement
  [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

```
  Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection
  ("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/testDb","name","pass");
  PreparedStatement updateemp = con.prepareStatement
  ("insert into emp values(?,?,?)");
  updateemp.setInt(1,23);
  updateemp.setString(2,"Roshan");
  updateemp.setString(3, "CEO");
  updateemp.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: PreparedStatement did not help ! it is the same :(

Comment: when compared to Statement Object PreparedStatement is better in performance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem you had, I don't know about others but I solved it by simply closing SQLplus! I didn't think that could solve it since some queries worked while sqlplus was running on the console, but I closed it and now every queries works and nothing hangs!

You may want to try this if you have our problem! exit Sqlplus on your console or any other database you are using, then try running your code again!

Answer (score -1):

use PreparedStatement instead

http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/

If you statement then every time it server will check for syntax so it consumes time
So go for PreparedStatement